# Jenkins Pipeline (aka Workfow) security with nodes

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

I want to create a Groovy script using Pipeline plugin in Jenkins handling the security for only some users can enter to the node.

This would be the example:

```
node('master') {
   //code..... more code
}

node('production') {
   //more code.....
}
```

I want to be able that only some users can run succesful the production node without using the input step that ask for only specific users/groups can approve it.

Is there a configuration option where I can configure the security of a specific Node about what users (or group) can execute scripts on it.

Note: I am using only Jenkisn 1.6 (not Cloudbees which it is with more complex security options)

Answer (score 1):

**Edited 04/20/2016 reflecting discussions in comment:**

**Update:** Goal: Preventing unauthorized user from executing jobs on a selection of Jenkins node.

**Update:** The [Job Restrictions Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin) referred by [luka5z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36749596/jenkins-pipeline-aka-workfow-security-with-nodes/36753390#comment61089301_36753390) would be a promising fit for the goal, when using it in conjunction with Role Strategy Plugin.

Give [Matrix-based security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) a try with this plugin [Role Strategy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin). First, you need to set users/anonymous group global role to have a very minimal access. Then you can set slave roles that only allow users to use node name in staring in a pattern e.g `QA_Slave*`, and only a small group, say admin, have all permissions on all slaves, which implies Production.

**Update:** Role Strategy Plugin can prevent user from modifying policy applied to node, but would not protect node from running a job it was tagged to. [*unauthorized slave assignment in job configuration*] where Job Restrictions Plugin would independently apply restrictions on the node level, without go extreme and taking all job configuration access away.

Comment: I meant, when you use Pipeline plugin (aka Workflow) you can execute groovy scripts inside your nodes, so I want to get an error when some user runs the scripts and execute the block of code of node 'production'

Comment: How I provide Slave roles? You meant? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try, the one you refer it is the it comes installed by default as a option security

Comment: I don't think this will accomplish your goal. This can protect specific jobs, but as long as a slave is tied to the job, they are free to run it. I kind of think you need [Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) to get you the user name and pass it to groovy script. Then you can validate them there.

Comment: I am already doing that in other builds, I just want to specify a more secure way to protect the node from Jenkins security instead develop the security in the script.

Comment: If you haven't already checked [Job Restrictions Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin) give it a look.

Comment: The Job Restrictions Plugin looks promising for the goal.

Comment: This is not currently supported by job-restriction-plugin and the creator ask for an issue to support Pipeline, I have created it: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34377